When $G$ is amenable is true that for a set $A \in p$ which is left piecewise syndetic then $\{ x: Ax^{-1} \in p \}$ is both sided syndetic?
Let be $G$ be a discrete group. I recall the definition of syndetic sets, thick sets and piecewise syndetic sets.
Definitions:

A set $A$ is left syndetic if there exist a finite $H \subset G$ such that $G=\bigcup_{h \in H} Ah^{-1}$
A set $A$ is left thick if for any finite $F \subset G$ we have that exists $x \in G$ such that $xF \subset A$
A set $A$ is left piecewise syndetic if there exists a left syndetic $S$ set and a thick $T$ set such that $A= S \cap T$

We have symmetric notions of right syndetic, right thick and right piecewise syndetic which in non-abelian group differs. But a set $S$ is left syndetic if and only if $S^{-1}$ is right syndetic.
If we consider the Stone-Cech compactification $\beta G$ and we define the following operation continuous on the left $ p \bullet q$, where $A \in p \bullet q$ if and only if $\{ x: Ax^{-1} \in p \} \in q$ and we consider the minimal two-sided ideal $K(\beta G, \bullet)$ we have the following results

A set is left piecewise syndetic if and only if $\overline{A} \cap K(\beta G, \bullet) \neq \emptyset$, where $\overline{A} = \{ p \in \beta G: A \in p \}$
$p \in K(\beta G,\bullet)$ if and only if for any $A \in p$ we have that $L_A=\{x: Ax^{-1} \in p \}$ is left syndetic

Similarly if we define a right continuous operation on $\beta G$ given by $p \circ q$ where $A \in p \circ q$ if and only if $\{ x: x^{-1}A \in q\} \in p$ we have the following

A set is right piecewise syndetic if and only if $\overline{A} \cap K(\beta G, \circ) \neq \emptyset$
$p \in K(\beta G,\circ)$ if and only if for any $A \in p$ we have that $R_A= \{x: x^{-1} A \in p \}$ is right syndetic.

Questions: If $G$ is also amenable, is it true that

For $A$ a left piecewise syndetic set exist $ p \in \overline{A} \cap K(\beta G, \bullet)$ such that $ L_A = \{ x: Ax^{-1} \in p \}$ is right syndetic?
What if $A$ is both left and right piecewise syndetic?
If 1. and 2. are false can somebody provide to me a counterexample?

If $G$ is non-amenable we should have a counterexample.
